# In Python, is it possible to pass function generics like C#?

Tags: python, generics

I would like to pass generic class to a function so I can return the same type as result.  My use case is writing ORM and a read function, which will take a table ORM, and return the same type as result, something like this:

```
def read<T>(id, fields="*") -> T:
```

Currently without typing, my code look like this:

```
def read(table, id, fields="*"):
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: It is actually possible, but it's mostly done for type hinting and requires a bit of work to make it really make it really work like generics in C# or Java.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You can *type annotate* generics, but that doesn't matter at runtime, that is strictly for static analysis. Python, a dynamically typed language, doesn't *need* generics, so it is really difficult to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, there are cases for that (e.g. repository pattern with base repository)

Comment: @sudden_appearance a case for *what*? What exactly are you describing in Python that would necessitate "generics" (again, something that *doesn't make sense* unless you are talking about statically typed languages)

Comment: Just pass the class itself as an argument? `def read(cls, id, fields="*"):`, and `cls` is a reference to a `User`, `Permission`, whatever class; the caller would just do `read(TableClass, myid, optional_fields)` when calling.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I suspect something like this is the correct answer, but as it stands, I don't think the exact use-case is clear from the way the question is written

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I posted an answer with an example

Comment: Again, your *question still doesn't make sense*. You posted an example "without typing", but it is a completely different function signature, so can you please elaborate on *exactly* what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, `get_where()` will be typed with `User`. And generics were never about type hinting. In java (JPA Repositories and load of web patterns) they are used to reduce code writing(as you don't have to reimplement same thing for 2 different classes. Generics once again are used to change function's behaviour depending on what class it's called from. So, in my `github` project I use `BaseRepository`, write default functions for yet unknown model. Then I extend It's typed version as a new class (`UsersRepository`) and have already implemented methods for it

Comment: @sudden_appearance python isn't Java. In Python, type annotating your function with generic type hints **has absolutely no effect** on your code, it actually makes your write *slightly more code*. So what you are describing is merely type hinting. If this question is "how to type hint generics" then that is already answered and should probably be closed as a duplicate

Comment: @sudden_appearance and what you are describing is simply inheritance, not generics as far as I can tell, unless you are talking about the type annotations, which again, could simply be omitted and your code would work exactly the same, because type annotations won't affect the way your code works (unless you are using some third-party library which makes use of type annotations at runtime, e.g. `pydantic`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I can make not only `User` but any class I want. There is no way I can do same via inheritance.

Comment: @sudden_appearance **but you don't need generic type annotations to do that**. so what you are saying doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I need them to differ `FooRepository` which works with `Foo` databse object and `BarRepository` which works with `Bar`, **and I use typehinting for that**. I will have to override `__init__` for every extended from BaseRepository (without typehinting) class and set `model` for that. But I do it with generics..

Comment: @sudden_appearance what? So you are *introspecting* the type annotations? It isn't clear what you mean. Again, type annotations *don't do anything at runtime* unless *you do something with them*. If the OP is talking about such a situation, it is certainly not clear from the question

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I get inherited typed generic class via `__orig_bases__[0]` as it's 1st class to be inherited from. Then i get it's types with `get_args()`, which return tuple, I get 1st element from that and that's a class reference. Is there anything wrong about it?

Comment: @sudden_appearance I am personally not a huge fan of using type hints at runtime, but this has taken off with pydantic, fastapi etc. In any case, this certainly *doesn't require* generics, and at the very least, you now need to document that your type annotations *have runtime effects*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, now I got what you mean............................................... After all this time. Yeah, I was kinda looking for in-code usable generics, not about typehinting only

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Python doesn't need generics because it is a dynamically typed langauge. This allows us to use so-called duck typing instead of explicit generics.

The first thing to note is that type annotations in python are only suggestions. They help static analysis tools such as code completion while you are writing code but are not enforced at run-time.

With that in mind, let's look at a non-annotated version of your function:

```
def read(table, fields="*"):
    pass
```

Here, python doesn't care what you pass for `table` as long as it supports the operations that are used inside of `read()`. This is what we call duck-typing: if it quacks like a duck, it's a duck. You see this in functions that act on sequeneces. For example:

```
def print_list(my_list):
    for el in my_list:
       print(el)
```

We can call `print_list()` with a list or a tuple:

```
print_list([1, 2, 3, 4])
print_list((1, 2, 3, 4))
```

In fact, anything that implements `__iter__()` and `__next__()` will work. This is the contract of the type and doesn't need to be specified with an interface, superclass, or generic type.

Now back to type hinting: there is a way to specify the "duck type contract" with type hinting, but I don't know the details off the top of my head. You could do some research to find out. As @juanpa.arrivillaga posted in a comment, you can look at `typing.Protocol` if you are interested in learning how to do the type hinting for cases like this.

Comment: I think you are referring to `typing.Protocol` for structural subtyping, which is sort of the static typing equivalent of duck typing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for that detail...in fact, "protocol" is probably a more accurate term than "contract" in my wording.

Comment: Simplest duck type contracts are made from `typing.Protocol`s; if the child class of the `Protocol` is decorated with `@typing.runtime_checkable`, you can use it for `isinstance`/`issubclass` checks at runtime of arbitrary instances/classes to see if they have the methods the `Protocol` expects, in which case they count as virtual subclasses of the `Protocol` class in question; if undecorated, they're purely for static type checkers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I recently was digging in Python type hinting abilities and came up with something like that

```
DBModel = TypeVar('DBModel')

class BaseRepository(Generic[DBModel]):

    def __init__(self):
        self.model: Type[DBModel] = get_args(self.__orig_bases__[0])[0]

    def get_where(self, *args) -> DBModel
        ...  # any logic with self.model
```

as a base class and

```
class UsersRepository(BaseRepository[User]):
    pass
```

`UsersRepository` will now have already implemented `get_where()` with `User` model and will also have reference for `User` inside `self.model`

I guess that's what you want. [Github](https://github.com/suddenAppearance/fastapi_urlshortener/tree/master) with source code (small project actually.)

Comment: So *you are* introspecting type hints.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it's not actually type hints but typed generics, but yes. Pydantic uses `<class_name>.__annotations__` dict for introspecting typehints and `get_args` in some cases

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you are making really. `typing.Generic` exists for the purpose of creating type hints. But I understand what you were getting at now

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yea, that code looks 0 pythonic way, I guess)

Comment: I mean, using type annotations this way is new enough that whether or not it is "pythonic" (i.e. idiomatic in Python) remains to be established. In any case, what you are doing here could have been done with a metaclass, so your API would be something like `class UserRepository(BaseReporsitory, model=User)` or something like that (note, prior to recent versions of Python, `typing.Generic` used a metaclass to do a lot of it's magic, but recent versions have allowed you to do it with special hooks, i.e. special "dunder methods" the runtime now recognizes, from the class itself)

Comment: *OR*, alternatively, the simplest way is to jsut use a class variable when you define your class `class UserRepository(BaseRepository): ` and then `model = User` in the class body. And then it will just work. In either case, it comes down to what consumers of your class need to do in slightly different ways, which you will need to document

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, but you can use multiple like `Generic[Type1, Type2, ....]`. Then it will actually make sense much more)

Comment: Well sure, you can do that with the other ways, `class UserRepository(BaseRepository, models = [Type1, Type2, ...])` or in the simplest, class-variable case, `models = [Type1, Type2, ...]`